# Why is there spacing in-between these columns that I am trying to create?

Tags: html, css, inline

I am trying to create a three column layout just for experimentation purposes but when I try to get these columns inline a gap appears between them which will be shown in the Codepen that I have linked.

I am trying to complete this just using percentage values and without using things like flex, is there something that I am missing?

Codepen Link: http://codepen.io/benrichi/pen/MJgOze

HTML

```
<head>
<title>Column Exercise</title>
</head>
<body>
 <div id="col1"> COLUMN 1 CONTENT TO BE PLACED HERE</div>
 <div id="col2"> COLUMN 2 CONTENT TO BE PLACED HERE </div>
 <div id="col3"> COLUMN 3 CONTENT TO BE PLACED HERE</div>
 <div id="footer"> FOOTER CONTENT TO BE PLACED HERE</div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
#col1 {
background-color:aqua;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
width: 30%;
display: inline-block;
height: 800px;
}

#col2 {
background-color: antiquewhite;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
width: 30%;
display: inline-block;
height: 800px;
}

#col3 {
background-color: aliceblue;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
width: 30%;
display: inline-block;
height: 800px;
}

#footer { 
margin: auto;
width: 90%;
background-color: aquamarine;
height: 200px;
}
```

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/

Comment: @sinisake thank you for the link to this, it was very helpful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can think of `inline-block` elements as *words*, so that gap is a normal space in between words.

One way of getting rid of that is removing the spaces in the HTML code as in:

```
<div id="col1"> COLUMN 1 CONTENT TO BE PLACED HERE</div><div id="col2"> COLUMN 2 CONTENT TO BE PLACED HERE </div><div id="col3"> COLUMN 3 CONTENT TO BE PLACED HERE</div><div id="footer"> FOOTER CONTENT TO BE PLACED HERE</div>
```

Here's youre reviewed codepen http://codepen.io/jpedroribeiro/pen/egOebg

Comment: Okay yeah thats good thank you, is there a way then to get the three columns to line up like the footer, the footer has its margins set to auto so that it lies in the middle of the display but I can't seem to get the columns to do this

Comment: Ah yes, I guess if you add a container to wrap them together, I've updated the CodePen.

Comment: Yeah thats what I've been trying to do but it just was not going well! So when you have applied the width of 33.33% to the columns, does that mean  they will be 33.33% of their parent, the container as opposed to the body now?

Comment: It's always related to the parent element, in this case, the "container".

Comment: That's where I was going wrong I think, and I guess that's also why you've got the overflow hidden on! Thank you for your help!